# How to iterate over a slice of mapped slices?

Tags: rust

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
for &xs in &[&[1, 2, 3].iter().map(|x| x + 1)] {
    for &x in xs {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:2:40: 2:49]>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 | /         for &x in xs {
4 | |             println!("{}", x);
5 | |         }
  | |_________^ the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:2:40: 2:49]>`
  |
  = note: `&std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:2:40: 2:49]>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

...which is very surprising, because I clearly see [how `std::Iter::Map` implements `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html).

Why does it complain and how to iterate over a slice of mapped slices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&T` can't be iterated as `next` mutates.

Thus if you have a `&Map<_, _>`, you can't iterate it.

You might not realize that `&[1,2,3].iter().map(|&x| x+1)` means

```
&([1,2,3].iter().map(|&x| x+1))
```

giving the reference.

Using `for &xs in &[&mut ...]` won't work either, as it requires moving `xs` out of an immutable reference. There is also currently no by-value iterator over fixed length arrays. I believe the easiest solution is

```
for xs in &mut [&mut [1, 2, 3].iter().map(|&x| x+1)] {
    for x in xs {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Note that this also requires fixing a problem with the `map` call, which didn't dereference its input.

Comment: Thanks. While this wasn't directly applicable to what I was trying to do, it helped me to wrap my head around Rust perspective on lifetimes and ownership.